# como proteger o acesso a um arquivo php?

Tags: php, jquery, htaccess

Galea estou usando o o plugin auto complete do Jquery. Ele funciona perfeitamente. Uso o jquery para chamar um arquivo php que faz a consulta no Bando de dados.

Chamo ele assim:

```
 $("#auto").autocomplete("Busca/Cadastros.php", {
        width: 500,
        multiple: false,
        matchContains: true,
        formatItem: formatItem,
        formatResult: formatResult
  });
```

O problema e que se eu digitar o caminho do arquivo ('caminho/Busca/Cadastros.php') no browser ele abre a consulta no BD. Como faço para bloquear esse arquivo? ou seja não ser possível abrir ele pelo navegador e que apenas meu jquery abra ele.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: ao autocomplete ele faz `get` ou `post` nesse arquivo.?

Comment: ele esta fazendo get

Comment: Impossível isso. Se o JS acessa, sempre é possível acesso direto.

Comment: Tem alguma forma de bloquear esta página via htacess para responder apenas ao ip do meu servidor?

Comment: ou posso mudar o método tbm.

Comment: Não é seu servidor quem acessa o script, é o browser do usuário.

Comment: @Bacco tem formas sim, uma delas já é restrigindo para `post` só aceitando requisição do mesmo site.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic nada impede de eu requisitar um post sem ser pela página. Tudo que o JS acessa, o usuário acessa direto. Sem exceção. Todo cabeçalho é gerado do lado do cliente, não tem como diferenciar uma requisição verdadeira de uma falsa. O máximo que dá pra fazer é enganar curioso (curiosos não sabem como fazer isso, simular requisições).

Comment: @Bacco mas, eu posso bloquear o tipo de requisição!!! e por ip!

Comment: mas se eu restringir para que o post so aceite requisição do próprio site, isso não resolve?

Comment: @HugoBorges o site não requisita, quem requisita é o navegador do usuário. Você só pode dificultar, mas não tem como impedir.

Comment: @Bacco entendi, caramba.

Comment: @HugoBorges eu não tenho muito mais como ajudar, acho que vc já entendeu que o problema é que vc tem que confiar no que o browser tá mandando. O que dá pra fazer são outras coisas, como limitar o numero de requisições e retorno por IP por hora pra ninguem baixar sua base toda de uma vez. Sites grandes como o dos correios não conseguem evitar bots, imagine nós "mortais". De qq forma, usar post. tokens etc pode ajudar a espantar curioso. Ao menos o pessoal fuçador não pega os dados. Mas qq um que saiba usar um CURL ou um socket básico simula tudo isso.

Comment: @Bacco entendi, bom tenho que tentar ao máximo achar solução que contornem isso. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Se essa requisição for POST no PHP você pode fazer antes de tudo:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

   // Todo seu código

}
```

Dessa forma por GET ele não vai poder acessar a URL pela barra de endereços do navegador. Mas estou vendo outras formas também, visto que alguém pode fazer um CURL POST nessa URL.

Para verificar se a requisição é AJAX:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

   // É Ajax, faça seu código aqui.

}
```

Seria bom seu `autocomplete` fazer a requisição POST.

É difícil pensar em todas as verificações, sempre haverá uma forma de burlar os processos. Evite o que você sabe e não se preocupe tanto com outras coisas.

**Backup** existe pra isso. **Restore** também, que é mais importante que o **backup** em si.

Seu código via POST e para enviar mais parâmetros no POST:

No parâmetro `data` você define mais variáveis. Lembrando que o `term` é o passado para o PHP fazer a busca.

```
$("#birds").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"Busca/Cadastros.php",
            data: { 
                 term: request.term,
                 outra_variavel: valor_outra_variavel
            },
            success: response,
        },
    },
    width: 500,
    multiple: false,
    matchContains: true,
    formatItem: formatItem,
    formatResult: formatResult
});
```

Comment: sim, atualmente estou usando GET. Tem alguma forma de bloquear esta página via htacess para responder apenas ao ip do meu servidor?

Comment: como falei no outro comentario acho que dessa forma o usuário pode fazer um CURL POST.

Comment: Ao menos que você verifique se a requisição é AJAX, como postei.

Comment: estou tendo fazer aqui. como faço para o jquery mandar um requisição Ajax?

Comment: Você já está mandando quando usa o Autocomplete. Mas está enviando via GET. Para fazer via POST você pode fazer o que o Vírgilio colocou no código que ele postou.

Comment: bom eu mantive meu jquery do mesmo jeito, usando o GET, porém no arquivo PHP eu fiz Omo vc me falou, verifiquei se a requisição é AJAX 'if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

   // É Ajax, faça seu código aqui.

}' e parece que deu certo.

Comment: @HugoBorges lembrando que por CURL dá pra mandar tanto o método igual do Ajax, como o HTTP_REFERER pra parecer que a origem é do seu site. Um curioso não consegue, mas alguém que consiga usar o console do browser ou alguma linguagem de programação continua acessando (mas é melhor do que nada)

Comment: @Bacco o que `HTTP_REFERER` interfere no `HTTP_ORIGIN` ?

Comment: @Gumball ambos são "simuláveis", só adiantei o assunto pra ficar mais completo. O ORIGIN é ruim de usar, pq é pouco browser que suporta. Se fizer coisa com ORIGIN, vai prejudicar um monte de usuário normal.

Comment: Bom saber disso.

Answer (score -1):

O ideal é você não colocar os arquivos do servidor (ou seja, o PHP) dentro da mesma pasta ou em pastas "filhas" na aplicação. Nesse caso, o caminho seria o seguinte:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete("../Busca/Cadastros.php", {
        width: 500,
        multiple: false,
        matchContains: true,
        formatItem: formatItem,
        formatResult: formatResult
  });
```

Mas é claro, você precisa limitar o acesso a qualquer coisa fora desse escopo. Dessa forma, não importa se o acesso é feito por GET ou POST, se o usuário tentar um acesso direto, ele não vai conseguir.

Comment: O "usuário" não pode remover o `../`?

Comment: Esse é o caminho onde o php está. O ".." significa que o arquivo está uma pasta acima do local atual (relativo ao js que está chamando o php), portanto você precisaria modificar também o local do seu arquivo php. A maneira mais segura de proteger o acesso é que só o sistema consiga acessar quando você for hospedar.

Comment: Quer disser que se o eu tiver `sistema/js` e `sistema/php` só porque o js faz `../file.php` o usuário não poderia acessar direto `sistema/php/file.php` é isso? '-'

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert, acho que ele quis dizer que será difícil o usuário saber exatamente qual o caminho do arquvo, por isso os `../`.

Comment: Errado, Gumball. Baseando-se nesse site: https://khalil-shreateh.com/khalil.shtml/index.php/websites/websites-development/106-best-5-ways-to-prevent-direct-access-to-a-php-file.html

Comment: @CleitonOliveira eu sou imperfeito. Eu erro, cara. Me perdoa. Vou tentar não fazer de novo. Obrigado pelo LINK.

Comment: Esqueci do quote do site:
"The best way to prevent direct access to files is to place them outside of the web-server document root (usually, one level above). You can still include them, but there is no possibility of someone accessing them through an http request."

O que ele diz é exatamente a minha resposta: a melhor maneira de prevenir acesso direto é colocar os arquivos fora da pasta-raiz do web-server, geralmente um nível acima. Você ainda consegue dar include, mas não há possibilidade de alguém acessar via http request.

Comment: @CleitonOliveira essa solução é boa se for algo pra um include de PHP, mas no caso, como é JS, precisa estar dentro da raiz do site senão nem o browser acessa.

Comment: @Bacco isso você resolve com o include.